# Line level with respect to GND

Tags: audio, ground

This seems like it should be a really easy one, but I'm having trouble finding a clear reference or explanation for it.

According to Wikipedia, [line level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level) has a peak around 0.5V, but I can't tell if that's GND to 0.5V, or -0.5V to 0.5V, or something else entirely. Which is it? (EDIT: Nevermind, it's now clear that it's the second case. Here's a [scope capture](http://mitat.tuu.fi/?p=45) linked from the Wikipedia page.)

The reason is that for switching ICs (mux, pot, etc), you need to have a V+..V- which exceeds the range of the analog signal, eg from [MCP42XXX datasheet p15](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/11195c.pdf):

> For linear operation, the analog input and output signals must be in
>   the range of VSS to VDD for the potentiometer...

Since the line level audio goes below GND, I assume I need a charge pump or virtual ground arrangement to use an IC such as the MCP42XXX. Is this so? Which is the recommended approach?

---

Edit: I discovered the answer to the first part of my question, but the second part remains relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a [charge pump](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/29493/2064) for this. Charge pumps are used to move *energy*, here you're only interested in a signal (voltage). BTW, a charge pump would leave nothing left of your signal. Adding a voltage can be as simple as a resistive adder, or, more sophisticated, you can use an opamp [summing amplifier](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_4.html).

[image]

The advantage of the opamp circuit is that, because of the virtual ground, input signals (your audio signal and the offset voltage) don't influence each other.

*Note*: if you want to use the digital potmeter to create a volume control, that's not a good idea. Volume control potmeters are logarithmic, this one is linear. For a volume control the [CS3310](http://www.cirrus.com/en/pubs/proDatasheet/CS3310_F1.pdf) has excellent specs, like click-free switching, though it's not cheap.

Comment: Okay, this is really helpful, thanks. Is there any other reason (apart from it being linear) not to use a simple digital pot as a volume control? If I don't need a lot of resolution in the end application, can I just do the log conversion in software? (especially if I put a 1M and 5K unit in series) That might not be cheaper than an $8 IC, but I just want to consider my options.

Comment: @mikepurvis - I guess you can approximate a logarithmic function with the two in series, though I think you'll end up with a lot less usable steps. Have you looked for a logarithmic potmeter, like [this one](http://datasheets.maxim-ic.com/en/ds/MAX5407.pdf). You'll find that they also have a limited number of steps. Another possibility is to make a linear pot more or less logarithmic by adding a resistor between the wiper and one end.